# Jquery each iteration of object

Tags: jquery, each

I have a messy loop within a loop.  The innermost loop needs to check an `id` against a collection of objects.  The objects in the collection each have an `employee_id` and a `team_id`:

[image]

I can pull this into jQuery function fine.  I usually use a key-value pair on my `each` statements:

```
$.each(teamIds, function(innerKey, id) {
      if(id === somevar){ ... etc }
}
```

With this collection of arrays, I need to catch the `team_id` to compare against a higher level loop, and then store the `employee_id` on the same loop if true.  This doesn't work with the key/value pair, as they are going to show a `team_id` and its `id` and then the `employee_id` in the next loop.  So, I've used the object within the final loop and *assumed it is being iterated.*

The following works perfectly:

```
$.each(empListTeam, function(key, arrayOfTeamAndEmp) {
     $.each(teamIds, function(innerKey, id) {
           $.each(arrayOfTeamAndEmp, function(key2, value) {
              if (key2 === 'team_id' && parseInt(id) === value) {
                 appliedEmpIds.push(arrayOfTeamAndEmp.employee_id);
              }
           });
     })
});
```

I can't find the right documentation to show that even though I'm passing `key2`, `value` through that final loop, that `arrayOfTeamAndEmp` is being iterated, and I'm doing this correctly.  Is this correct, or am I going to have issues with this mess?  Or... am I just totally missing an obviously better way to construct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not yet entirely sure what the purpose of your script is. But if you want to collect and reorganize your data in a way that you have arrays holding the employee_ids as team members, you can do the folling (simplified) single loop version:

```js
var appliedEmpIds={};
var coll={items:[
 {team_id:1,employee_id:2},
 {team_id:1,employee_id:3},
 {team_id:2,employee_id:4},
 {team_id:2,employee_id:5},
 {team_id:2,employee_id:6},
 {team_id:3,employee_id:7}
]};
$.each(coll.items,function(i,o){
  (appliedEmpIds[o.team_id]=appliedEmpIds[o.team_id] || []).push(o.employee_id);
});
console.log('jQuery:',appliedEmpIds);

// you can do the same also in Vanilla JS as

var aei={};
coll.items.forEach(function(o,i){
  (aei[o.team_id]=aei[o.team_id] || []).push(o.employee_id);
});
console.log('Vanilla:',aei);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @cars10m, this is really helpful.  I'm pretty sure the object is iterated, and this is proving true through all testing -- I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something that isn't documented and will bite me later.  But, I think you are spot-on, it may be better to just reorganize the data to be flat as you suggested.  Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right: `jquery.each()` *does* indeed interate over all properties of a given object. But it would not really be helpful in your case, as you would end up with nested loops and ugly `if` conditions.